# angularjs uigrid not loading array

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

the uigrid in angularjs is not loading array objects. this error occurs when I changed the select query to stored procedure.

heres the returned results using stored procedure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCyAp.jpg)
This array results doesn't display the data.

heres the returned results using the select query which displays the data. How do I change the array data to object?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMREl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions on my own.. 
here's the code at the controller on server side...

```
     con.query("CALL `sp_tviselect`", function(err, result) {
      if(err){
          throw err;
      } else {
          //console.log(result);
          res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
      }
     });
```

here's the code on the controller at client side

```
  $http.get('/api/tvi/list')
    .success(function(data) {
     var newObj = {};
     for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
     {
        newObj[i]=data[i];
     }
     $scope.gridOptions.data = newObj[0];
      newObj[0].forEach( function addRows( row, index ){
      row.businesstype = row.businesstype==='DTI' ? '1' : '2';
       });
   });
```

first I convert the raw data pocket into json string format. Then at the client side I get the list element of the array which is index 0, then put it to the object variable.

I hope this will help other people. Thanks